# pyramid custom oauth2 decorator

Tags: python, decorator, pyramid, oauth-provider

Currently using Kevin Van Wilder oauth2 server project http://code.google.com/p/pyramid-oauth2/, its in development, but great part of the functionality working well in my project but i had this problem with one of his decorators, i am new to decorators and as i said is in development so i am not sure if its already done or actually a decorator per se, i commented some relevant lines uppercase i got problems with,  can i fix or use this?, or do i need to make it using functools wrap function... some guidance would be appreciated

```
def oauth2(allowed_scopes=[], optional=False):
    def wrap(view_fn):
        def new_fn(incoming_request):
            # get token
            request = OAuth2Request(incoming_request)
            token = request.access_token
            # handle token
            if token:
                #oauth2_context = get_token_context.delay(token.get('token')).get() I AM NOT USING CELERY
                oauth2_context = get_token_context(token.get('token'))
                # stop if token contains no valid information
                if not oauth2_context.valid:
                    raise OAuth2ErrorHandler.error_invalid_token(token.get('type'))
                # not mandatory use of oauth, but valid token
                elif optional:
                    return view_fn(request=incoming_request, oauth2_context=oauth2_context)
                # validate scope
                elif has_valid_scope(oauth2_context.scopes, allowed_scopes):
                    return view_fn(request=incoming_request, oauth2_context=oauth2_context)
                # return oauth error for invalid token
                else:
                    return OAuth2ErrorHandler.error_invalid_token(token.get('type'))
            # no token
            else:
                if optional:
                    return view_fn(request=incoming_request, oauth2_context=None)
                else:
                    raise HTTPUnauthorized('request contained no access token.')

        new_fn.__doc__ = view_fn.__doc__
        #new_fn.__name__ = view_fn.__name__ WITH THIS IT DOESNT WORK, COMMENTED IT
        new_fn.view_name = view_fn.view_name MAYBE ITS LIKE THIS?
        #return new_fn CANT RETURN HERE, IT GOES DIRECTLY TO THE VIEW, COMMENTED IT
    return wrap
```